# c++ template container memcpy

Tags: c++, templates, containers, memcpy

I am try to write a container memcpy function.
However, I can't pass my container as parameter.
Could anyone give me a hint?

At this moment, I create 1 more function inside class called DIn, to put information.

I try to achieve remove DIn function, and use like normal memory copy to do this.

Could somebody give me a help?

Best regards
TINGMING

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>  

template <typename VECTOR_TYPE = char,int VECTOR_SIZE = 256>
class vector{
private:
    int SIZE;
    VECTOR_TYPE ARRAY[VECTOR_SIZE];
public:
    vector():SIZE(VECTOR_SIZE){
    }
    VECTOR_TYPE& operator[](int nIndex){
        assert(nIndex >= 0 && nIndex < SIZE);
        return ARRAY[nIndex];
    }
    void DIn(VECTOR_TYPE data,int nIndex){
        assert(nIndex >= 0 && nIndex < SIZE);
        ARRAY[nIndex] = data;
    }
    int sizeof_vector(){
        return SIZE;
    }
};

template <typename VECTOR_TYPE,int VECTOR_SIZE1,int VECTOR_SIZE2>
void vector_memcpy(
    vector <VECTOR_TYPE,VECTOR_SIZE1> *target,int tIdx,
    vector <VECTOR_TYPE,VECTOR_SIZE2> source,int sIdx,
    int Length)
{

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<Length;i++)    
        target->DIn(source[sIdx+i],tIdx+i);
}


int main()
{
    vector <int,16> AV;
    vector <int,32> BV;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        AV[i] = i*15;

    vector_memcpy(&BV,0,AV,0,16);
    vector_memcpy(&BV,16,BV,0,16);

    for(i=0;i<16;i++)
        printf("%2d: %3d %3d %3d\n",i,AV[i],BV[i],BV[i+16]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have build errors? Do you have crashes? Could you please edit your question to contain a little more details, like those just asked? Also, if you get build errors please edit your question to included *all* of them in an unedited form.

Comment: you shouldn't be passing by pointer and by value but by reference and const reference. Or simply use std::array which does everything you want and probably smarter

Comment: Have you tried explicitly specifying template typenames in your calls to `vector_memcpy`? It could help with debugging

Comment: I copy paste this code to VS2010 threre aren't any errors, even warnings. BTW isn't safer to check vectors values with C++ I/O? (It's easy to get unnoticeable error with printf() specifiers and parameters).